# Super key does not work

Tags: linux, keyboard, windows-10

I have a dual boot configuration in my PC with windows 10 and right now also linux mint. For about a month now windows start key (Super) stopped working on both windows and the linux distro I had back then.

For example in windows I couldn't press `Super + R` to run a program and in mint Super wouldn't open the start menu.

Now I installed i3wm in mint and as in my laptop I want Mod4 (Super) as a modifier for the windows manager. When I change the config from Mod1 (Meta key) to Mod4 (Super key) nothing works. Not even `$Mod + Enter` to open a new terminal.

I installed xkeybinds and I run the `xkeybind -mk` command and it seems like Super gives no signal to the OS. When I press `Super + r` it's the same output when I just press `r`.

I think this might have to do with the keyboard (it's a cheap "gaming" one I bought cause I needed a keyboard with lights on the keys) so before I go buy a new one I'd like to ask you if there is anything I can do or if you have an idea of what the problem is.

Everything else works in the keyboard and it has no drivers associated with it on the internet.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Borrow another keyboard to test with. If that works you know the problem is with your keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the super key work anywhere with anything? Have another computer to test it on? The quickest 100% reliable method to test hardware like this is to try it on another computer.

From your xkeybinds test it sounds like the key itself is dirty or stuck or broken or something, and just doesn't work.

If the super key doesn't work on another computer, then it's definitely the key (or the whole keyboard) itself that doesn't work.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: The question is essentially this line: *"before I go buy a new one I'd like to ask you if there is anything I can do or if you have an idea of what the problem is."*

Comment: Well, I just tested it on my laptop, I should do this before asking. It won't work there as well. It just seems very strange that both the right and left Super keys are the only thing not working in the entire keyboard.